Make ball bounce in react native
I am currently working on react native project where i need to build pong game, but i ran in to a bug. I need to get ball to bounce of the blue platform byt right now it just flys thrue the platform.
Can someone explain how fix the problem?
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, PanResponder, Animated, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const BLUE_ISLAND_WIDTH = 150;
const BLUE_ISLAND_HEIGHT = 50;
const BALL_SIZE = 30;
const FALLING_SPEED = 9.2;
const BOUNCE_VELOCITY_MULTIPLIER = 0.8;

export default function Canvas() {
    const [blueIslandPosition] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 600 }));
    const [ballPosition] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 180, y: 400 })); // Position of the small black square
    const [selectedLevel, setSelectedLevel] = useState(null);
    const [gameStarted, setGameStarted] = useState(false);

    const fallingSpeedRef = useRef(null);

    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
            const newX = parseFloat(blueIslandPosition.x) || 0;
            Animated.event(
                [null, { dx: newX }],
                { useNativeDriver: false }
            )(event, gestureState);
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: () => {
            // No need for release action in this version
        },
    });

    const CustomButton = ({ title, onPress, style }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={style}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    const handleLevelPress = (level) => {
        setSelectedLevel(level);
    };

    const handleStartPress = () => {
        if (selectedLevel) {
            let fallingSpeed = FALLING_SPEED;
            switch (selectedLevel) {
                case 'Medium':
                    fallingSpeed *= 1.5;
                    break;
                case 'Hard':
                    fallingSpeed *= 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            console.log('Starting game with level:', selectedLevel, 'and falling speed:', fallingSpeed);
            setGameStarted(true);

            fallingSpeedRef.current = setInterval(() => {
                const newY = ballPosition.y._value + fallingSpeed;
                ballPosition.y.setValue(newY);
            }, 1000 / 60);
        } else {
            console.log('Please select a level before starting the game.');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if (fallingSpeedRef.current) {
                clearInterval(fallingSpeedRef.current);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    const handleCollision = () => {
        const ballX = ballPosition.x._value;
        const ballY = ballPosition.y._value;
        const islandX = blueIslandPosition.x._value;
        const islandY = blueIslandPosition.y._value;

        if (
            ballX >= islandX && ballX <= islandX + BLUE_ISLAND_WIDTH &&
            ballY >= islandY && ballY <= islandY + BLUE_ISLAND_HEIGHT
        ) {
            const newXVelocity = -BOUNCE_VELOCITY_MULTIPLIER * (ballX - (islandX + BLUE_ISLAND_WIDTH / 2));
            const newYVelocity = -BOUNCE_VELOCITY_MULTIPLIER * (ballY - (islandY + BLUE_ISLAND_HEIGHT / 2));
            ballPosition.x.setValue(ballX + newXVelocity);
            ballPosition.y.setValue(ballY + newYVelocity);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const animationLoop =() => {
            const newY = ballPosition.y._value + (gameStarted? FALLING_SPEED : 0);
            ballPosition.y.setValue(newY);

            handleCollision();

            requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
        };

        animationLoop();

        return () => {
            cancelAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
        };
    }, [ballPosition, blueIslandPosition, gameStarted]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{ width: BLUE_ISLAND_WIDTH, height: BLUE_ISLAND_HEIGHT, backgroundColor: "#e52441", position: "absolute", top: 100, left: 120, borderRadius: 100 }}>
                <Animated.View {...panResponder.panHandlers} style={{ width: BLUE_ISLAND_WIDTH, height: BLUE_ISLAND_HEIGHT, backgroundColor: "#1875FF", position: "absolute", marginTop: -10, transform: [{ translateX: blueIslandPosition.x }, { translateY: blueIslandPosition.y }], borderRadius: 100 }} />
            </View>
            <Animated.View style={{ position: "absolute", top: ballPosition.y, left: ballPosition.x, borderRadius: BALL_SIZE, width: BALL_SIZE, height: BALL_SIZE, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
            {!gameStarted && (
                <View style={styles.difficultyPanel}>
                    <Text style={styles.panelText}>Paddle Dash</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.panelText}>Level</Text>
                    <View style={styles.levelButtons}>
                        <CustomButton title="Easy" onPress={() => handleLevelPress('Easy')} style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: selectedLevel === 'Easy' ? "#1875FF" : "white" }]} />
                        <CustomButton title="Medium" onPress={() => handleLevelPress('Medium')} style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: selectedLevel === 'Medium' ? "#1875FF" : "white" }]} />
                        <CustomButton title="Hard" onPress={() => handleLevelPress('Hard')} style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: selectedLevel === 'Hard' ? "#1875FF" : "white" }]} />
                    </View>
                    <CustomButton title="Start" onPress={handleStartPress} style={styles.startButton} />
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}


I have tried to ask chat gpt, but it just give me bad answers. And i can't find information somewhere else.
